# Keras model is doing batch size of 1 when using fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I fit_generator with my batch generator it uses a batch size of 1, it does 1 step increment for each epoch. What am I doing wrong.

I have tried changing batch size arguments for my batch generator but still the same.

My batch generator function:

```
def batchGenerator(imgs, steerings, batchSize, isTraining):

    while True:
        batchImg = []
        batchSteering = []

        for i in range(batchSize):
            randIndex = random.randint(0, len(imgs) - 1)
            if isTraining:
                img, steering = randomAugment(imgs[randIndex], steerings[randIndex])
            else:
                img = imgs[randIndex]
                steering = steerings[randIndex]

            img = imgPreprocess(img)

            batchImg.append(img)
            batchSteering.append(steering)

        yield (np.asarray(batchImg), np.asarray(batchSteering))
```

This is my fit_generator arguments:

```
history = model.fit_generator(batchGenerator(X_train, y_train, 300, 1),
                              steps_per_epoch = 300,
                              epochs = 10,
                              validation_data = batchGenerator(X_valid, y_valid, 200, 0),
                              validation_steps = 200,
                              verbose = 1,
                              shuffle = 1)
```

When I run this the batch size seems to be 1, as for each epoch it is being incremented by 1. For each epoch it does 0/300, 1/300, 2/300, 3/300, etc.

What is going on?

Comment: what is the output of `len(X_train)`

Comment: Try changing `steps_per_epoch` to something else than 300. You can see the diference

Comment: @SreeramTP The output is 9848

Comment: @SreeramTP I tried changing it, but I still get 1 increments.

Comment: it will only go by 1 increment. You can read what `steps_per_epochs` is over here https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator

Comment: @SreeramTP So when using the fit_generator, the increments will always be 1?

Comment: see my answer. let me know whether it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generator has no issue and your code is fine too. The way you interpret the output is wrong.

From the docs, you can see

> steps_per_epoch: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.

Normally `steps_per_epochs` is set as `X_train.shape[0]//batch_size`

While training, the training is done for `steps_per_epochs` batches and one epoch is treated as completed. Since the data is taken in a random order there is no other way to tell the model that one epoch is over.

While training you can see `0/300, 1/300, 2/300, 3/300` and so on till `300/300`. It is quite normal. This means your model is trained for `300` steps where there batch size for each step is `300` (since you gave batch size as 300)

If you gave batch size as let's say 10, and steps_per_epoch as `100` you can see while training `1/100, 2/100` so on till `100/100` which means, your model is trained for `100` steps and each step is essentialy a batch of `10` samples

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your `steps_per_epoch` should always be length of training data divided by `batch_size`, i.e. in this case `X_train.shape[0]//batch_size`.

Also, the way you are shuffling your data with the random index, it will mean some samples might be selected more than once and some, never. You can also think about random shuffling the entire training set first, and then pick sequential batches of data for training. I just wanted to point this out, if you missed.

#### Edit

```
def batchGenerator(imgs, steerings, batchsize, isTraining):
    while True:
        start = 0
        end = batchsize

        while start  < len(imgs): 
            x = imgs[start:end]
            y = steerings[start:end]
            if isTraining:            
                x , y = randomAugment(x, y)
            
            yield x, y

            start += batchsize
            end += batchsize
```

Maybe try something like this. You can handle the shuffling later if this works.

Comment: It still increments by 1.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the `fit` function, the output of `fit_generator` is the count of batches and not of training examples. Consequently,an increment of 1 means that one more batch has been processed. With `steps_per_epoch` you define how many batches will be processed per epoch.

By definition, one epoch is finished when each training example has been processed once. This is why people suggest to set steps_per_epoch to:

```
steps_per_epoch=number_of_examples//batch_size
```

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification. Much appreciated.